# adding drop down menu item to existing menu

Tags: menus

I am a newbee ... so go easy on me :-)   I am trying to create a home for sale site for my house.   I have a menu across the top that among other this has a "gallery" selection.   I would like to have three galleries and the menu displayed such that when you hover over the present "gallery" menu, three options can be selected ... Gallery A, Gallery B, or Gallery c.   Is this something that is easily accomplished, or would extensive coding be required?

Existing home page ... http://www.fullcircletherapy.com/home

Comment: It depends on the theme you're using. When you manage the menu, you should be able to drag the 3 galleries (Gallery A, Gallery B, Gallery C) under the main "Gallery" menu item, so they are indented. Then, save the menu and see whether this works with your theme. If not, the simplest thing to do would be to either switch themes or look for a menu plugin that may be compatible with your theme.

Comment: https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-navigation-menu-in-wordpress-beginners-guide/